# How can I program a custom popup Window in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, popup

My Qt application consists of several screens added on a `QStackedLayout()`. Now after some useraction I would like a little popup window that confirms the action and disappears after a few seconds. What I would like is a gray rectangle with black border and some text in it. No buttons, no titlebar.

I tried to do it with QMessage Box (see code below) but in general it doesnt seem to be possible to adjust border styles for `QMessageBox()`. Also the size can't be adjusted.

```
QMessageBox* tempbox = new QMessageBox;
tempbox->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);  //removes titlebar
tempbox->setStandardButtons(0); //removes button
tempbox->setText("Some text");
tempbox->setFixedSize(800,300); //has no effect
tempbox->show();
QTimer::singleShot(2000, tempbox, SLOT(close()));  //closes box after 2 seconds
```

So, how can I program a custom popup Window in Qt?

Comment: ***Also the size can't be adjusted.*** I know this is wrong since in one of my current applications I set the width of the message box to display a long message. I'll have to check my implementation later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to recommend the [Windows Flags Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html) of the Qt docs. It provides a nice sample to play around with this topic. In this sample, a `QWidget` is derived to show the effect of the distinct flags. This brought me to the idea that probably any `QWidget` can be used for this if the appropriate [`Qt::WindowFlags`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) are set. I choosed `QLabel` because

- it can display text
- it inherits from `QFrame` and, thus, can have a frame.

Source code `testQPopup.cc`:

```
// standard C++ header:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Qt header:
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTimer>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  cout << QT_VERSION_STR << endl;
  // main application
#undef qApp // undef macro qApp out of the way
  QApplication qApp(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QMainWindow qWin;
  qWin.setFixedSize(640, 400);
  qWin.show();
  // setup popup
  QLabel qPopup(QString::fromLatin1("Some text"),
    &qWin,
    Qt::SplashScreen | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
  QPalette qPalette = qPopup.palette();
  qPalette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, QColor(0xff, 0xe0, 0xc0));
  qPopup.setPalette(qPalette);
  qPopup.setFrameStyle(QLabel::Raised | QLabel::Panel);
  qPopup.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
  qPopup.setFixedSize(320, 200);
  qPopup.show();
  // setup timer
  QTimer::singleShot(1000,
    [&qPopup]() {
    qPopup.setText(QString::fromLatin1("Closing in 3 s"));
  });
  QTimer::singleShot(2000,
    [&qPopup]() {
    qPopup.setText(QString::fromLatin1("Closing in 2 s"));
  });
  QTimer::singleShot(3000,
    [&qPopup]() {
    qPopup.setText(QString::fromLatin1("Closing in 1 s"));
  });
  QTimer::singleShot(4000, &qPopup, &QLabel::hide);
  // run application
  return qApp.exec();
}
```

I compiled with VS2013 and Qt 5.6 on Windows 10 (64 bit). The image below shows a snaphot:

[image: Snapshot of testQPopup.exe]

To make the popup better visible (and because I liked it), I changed the background color of the `QLabel` for popup. And, I couldn't resist to add a little countdown.